# building a typed allSettled() function off of Bluebird

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I'd like to define a helper function `allSettled()` in Typescript which models the pattern discussed on Bluebird's site here:

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html

My attempt is here:

```
export function allSettled<T>(promiseHash: IDictionary<Promise<T>>): IDictionary<Promise.Inspection<T>> {
  return Promise.props(
    Object
      .keys(promiseHash)
      .reduce((newObject: IDictionary<Promise<T>>, key: string) => {
        newObject[key] = promiseHash[key].reflect();
        return newObject;
      }, {})
  );
}
```

where I've defined `IDictionary` as:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
};
```

Functionally, the script above *does* work but Typescript complains that:

> Type 'Bluebird' is not assignable to type 'IDictionary>'.
>     Index signature is missing in type 'Bluebird'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try IDictionary<Promise<T>> instead of IDictionary<T>?

Comment: but that wouldn't be accurate, right? A `Promise.props` structure is hash object with string keys and values are _promises_ which will fulfill to <T>. Just out of interest though I did try it and it didn't work either.